# Creating Azure storage authorization header using python

Tags: azure, utf-8, azure-blob-storage, sha256, azure-storage-account

I am trying to create the Authorization header for using Azure storage REST APIs. What a nightmare. The reason I am trying to do this is because I am trying to use a workflow builder (Alteryx) to call the API so my only programmatic options are Alteryx, python, or command line.

I think I'm close, but I just don't understand these last three lines of code, following this article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-rest-api-auth?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json

// Now turn it into a byte array.
byte[] SignatureBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MessageSignature);

// Create the HMACSHA256 version of the storage key.
HMACSHA256 SHA256 = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(storageAccountKey));

// Compute the hash of the SignatureBytes and convert it to a base64 string.
string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(SHA256.ComputeHash(SignatureBytes));

So if I follow this correctly, I have to create a SHA256 version of the storage key but then I make a SHA256 hash of the SHA256 hash of the signaturebytes?

I'm current googling and not getting far, but basically trying to do the same thing above in .net using python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python, you can just use this line of code:

```
signed_string = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode(storage_account_key), msg=string_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()
```

Here is the complete code of using [List blobs api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs):

```
import requests
import datetime
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

storage_account_name = 'xx'
storage_account_key = 'xxx'
container_name='aa1'
api_version = '2017-07-29'
request_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')

string_params = {
    'verb': 'GET',
    'Content-Encoding': '',
    'Content-Language': '',
    'Content-Length': '',
    'Content-MD5': '',
    'Content-Type': '',
    'Date': '',
    'If-Modified-Since': '',
    'If-Match': '',
    'If-None-Match': '',
    'If-Unmodified-Since': '',
    'Range': '',
    'CanonicalizedHeaders': 'x-ms-date:' + request_time + '\nx-ms-version:' + api_version + '\n',
    'CanonicalizedResource': '/' + storage_account_name +'/'+container_name+ '\ncomp:list\nrestype:container'
}

string_to_sign = (string_params['verb'] + '\n' 
                  + string_params['Content-Encoding'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Language'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Length'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-MD5'] + '\n' 
                  + string_params['Content-Type'] + '\n' 
                  + string_params['Date'] + '\n' 
                  + string_params['If-Modified-Since'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-Match'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-None-Match'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-Unmodified-Since'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Range'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['CanonicalizedHeaders']
                  + string_params['CanonicalizedResource'])

signed_string = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode(storage_account_key), msg=string_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()

headers = {
    'x-ms-date' : request_time,
    'x-ms-version' : api_version,
    'Authorization' : ('SharedKey ' + storage_account_name + ':' + signed_string)
}

url = ('https://' + storage_account_name + '.blob.core.windows.net/'+container_name+'?restype=container&comp=list')

r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
print(r.status_code)
print('\n\n'+r.text)
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: OMG, thank you! This is exactly what I needed. It is working. Can't wait to try uploading blobs now that I have this pattern.

Comment: @KevinD, could you please help mark it as an answer? Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, still a SO N00b.